# ¿Por qué los labels muestran el texto después de asignarlo a su atributo Text?

Tags: c#

Si hago algo como esto:

```
lblShift.Text = "hola";
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

El label muestra el texto después de que pasan los 10 segundos y no antes, ¿por qué?

Acabo de descubrir que si pongo un `Refresh()` antes del `Sleep()` sí se actualiza antes, pero ¿por qué si no se pone se actualiza después?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque el manejador de eventos y threads, ejecuta las cosas en orden.

Entonces lo que esta pasando es que esta ejecutando ese evento que decis (no aclaras cual es), y dentro de ese evento esta una instruccion que le dice que espere 10 segundos.

Cuando se ejecuta el cambio al label, este dispara un evento en el mismo thread que le dice que se tiene que refrescar, pero como esta procesando el evento que escribio el label, entonces sigue ese "hilo" hasta que termina.

Cuando le decis que refresque (el refresh forzado), entonces si dispara el evento refresh, y despues sigue procesando las instrucciones de este procedimiento.